# is there a specific word to call a situation if two keywords are performing tasks opposite to each other

Tags: vocabulary

I have 2 keywords lets say "foo1" and "foo2" , these both keywords corresponds to some function they are assigned but I was performing some tests and noticed that I select "foo1" the program was performing the functionality of "foo2"and vice-versa, now I have to inform my boss in an email and I guess "mix up" is not a correct terminology to use , is there a specific term that I can use to report this "mix up"?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong  but wouldn't "contradicting" be used just if they are performing a functionality they are not supposed to be like generally ? maybe I didn't explain myself in a correct manner , the code should be performing a functionality for "foo1" which is supposed to be performed by "foo2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the functionality of foo1 and foo2 have been [interchanged](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/interchange) or [transposed](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transpose).

My preference would be to use the word "**interchanged**". It's first definition in the American Heritage dictionary is:

> 1. To switch each of (two things) into the place of the other.

Which I think might be exactly what you mean.

Comment: ahhh yes! thanks a lot , this word was at the back of my mind and for some reason I couldn't recall it , thanks